# SCNetworkReachability connects on WIFI but not connecting on Cellular

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, reachability

I am trying to connect to 3g network but scnetwork reachability is not working fine... 
It works fine on wifi but error on 3g or edge

Here is the code...

```
SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = { 0, &g_con, NULL, NULL, NULL };
SCNetworkReachability *reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName( NULL, "www.google.com" );
if( ! reachability )
    return;

if( ! SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback( reachability, reachabilityCallback, &context ) )
    return;

SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop( reachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode );
```

Comment: Did you make strong link to `reachability` instance?